# How to make work jquery "swipe" with scroll on iPad?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ios, ipad

I have two divs, standing next to each other. In addition to `click` event I added a `swiperight` and `swipeleft` to do something. But when I add these `swipe` events, scroll doesn't work anymore on iPad. On PCs there's no problem!

Is there any other way to make them compatible with each other on iPad (touch screen devices)?

Merci!

Comment: Can you show what you have tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

**Found a solution:**

http://stephband.info/jquery.event.swipe/

Swipe events are a thin wrapper built on top of move events (stephband.info/jquery.event.move). Move events, by default, override native scrolling, as they assume that you want to move something rather than scroll the window. To re-enable scrolling, call e.preventDefault() inside a movestart handler.

In the example above, we want to be able to swipeleft and swiperight, but scroll up and down. Inside a movestart handler, the direction of the finger is moving is calculated and the event is prevented if it is found to be moving up or down::

```js
jQuery('.mydiv')
.on('movestart', function(e) {
  // If the movestart is heading off in an upwards or downwards
  // direction, prevent it so that the browser scrolls normally.
  if ((e.distX > e.distY && e.distX < -e.distY) ||
      (e.distX < e.distY && e.distX > -e.distY)) {
    e.preventDefault();
  }
});
```